# How do I create a user through membership without being logged into their account after creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm having a logged in user create another user (different roles) using Membership.CreateUser. After creating the user, the logged in user automatically gets the boot and the newly created user is logged in.

The goal would be to have the logged in user create a new user and continue working within the app being logged in under their own credentials.

I'm not sure how to change this. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterClientContact(RegisterClientContactViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Create Generic password - First initial Last initial 1234
            string genericPassword = model.FirstName.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + model.LastName.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + "1234";


            //Attempt to register the Client Contact
            MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
            Membership.CreateUser(model.Email, genericPassword, model.Email, null, null, true, null, out createStatus);



            if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.Email, "Client");
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false /*create persistent cookie*/);

                Person person = new Person();
                person.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                person.LastName = model.LastName;
                person.Email = model.Email;
                person.Phone = model.Phone;
                person.Active = true;

                db.Persons.Add(person);
                db.SaveChanges();

                ClientContact clientPerson = new ClientContact();
                clientPerson.ClientPersonId = person.Id;
                clientPerson.Title = model.Title;
                clientPerson.ClientId = model.ClientId;

                db.ClientPersons.Add(clientPerson);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "ClientContact");
            }
        }

        return View("An Error has occured");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting these two lines.

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(model.Email, "Client"); 
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Email, false /*create persistent cookie*/);
```

Comment: that worked great. I didn't delete the first line because I need to assign a role to this newly created user. But deleting the second line was the trick. Thanks!